# Two Search pages, One search form

Tags: pages, search, navigation

I have a search form that I want to place in multiple pages (it will be in different header types) I do this by using the 'get search form' function. On my Search form I have radio sections listing two custom post types 'poster' and 'house'.

I have two different search pages for each post type. I want them to be separate because I want to add the search separate search pages on my Navigation e.g. "search for a poster", "search for a house".

Is there a way how I can get the search form to redirect the user to either the  "search for a house" page or the "search for a poster" depending on the radio button selected before the entry was submitted?.

Preferably I would like to keep all the necessary coding within the Searcform.php file if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by poster? A user? A post type? A taxonomy term?

Comment: 'poster' is my post type @TomJNowell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my Solution, I used Onclick attributes for the radio buttons to change the 'actions' of elements within the form.

```
<form  id="searchme" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/postersearch" method="get">
<ul class=" four columns inline-list offset-by-one">
  <li><label for="radio4"><input name="post_type" CHECKED type="radio" id="radio4" onclick="document.getElementById('searchme').action='<?php echo site_url(); ?>/postersearch'; document.getElementById('searchsubmit').value='Search For Posters';"/> Events</label></li>
  <li><label for="radio5"><input name="post_type"  type="radio" id="radio5" onclick="document.getElementById('searchme').action='<?php echo site_url(); ?>/housesearch'; document.getElementById('searchsubmit').value='Search For Houses';"/> Locations</label></li>
</ul>
<input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Search For posters"  style="width:100%"/>             
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hook into `'template_include'` and change the template here.

Made up example, not tested:

```
add_action( 'template_include', 'wpse_96472_search_template' );

function wpse_96472_search_template( $template )
{
    if ( ! is_search() )
        return $template;

    if ( empty ( $_GET['post_type'] ) )
        return $template;

    if ( 'poster' === $_GET['post_type'] )
        return get_template_directory() . '/poster-search-template.php';

    if ( 'house' === $_GET['post_type'] )
        return get_template_directory() . '/house-search-template.php';

    return $template;
}
```

You have to change the template names and the `$_GET` parameter name of course.

Comment: Hey @toscho , thanks for your contribution. I found an answer. I was able to do what I wanted using "Onclick events" on the radio buttons in the search form: 

Below is what I did for the radio button Poster. 

<label for="radio4"><input name="post_type" type="radio" id="radio4" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').action='<?php echo site_url(); ?>/postersearch'; document.getElementById('searchsubmit').value='Search For Poster';"/> Events</label></li>


I did the same for the House radio button.

Thanks

Comment: @user28123 Please share your solution with us. You can answer your own question in a real answer.

Comment: i updated the answer with my solution @toscho

Comment: @user28123 Please **never** put your solution into the **question**. Write a real answer – use the **answer** field for that, then mark this answer as _accepted_.

Comment: damn, guess using this site isn't as easy as I thought it would be @toscho